# What is the difference between *smart_ptr and *smart_ptr.get()

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

As well as I understand, dereferencing - `*smart_ptr` , and `get()` + dereferencing `*smart_ptr.get()` doing the same thing with smart pointers, but may be there is something under the hood that I'm not aware of, cause I've seen a lot of cases there the second approach was used, so what is the point? Does it affect performance in any way?

Comment: There is no difference (other than one is 6 characters longer than the other).  All standard smart pointer types overload [`operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*), which dereferences the contained pointer, same as dereferencing the result of `.get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a functional standpoint, there is no difference between `*smart_ptr` and `*(smart_ptr.get())`, as they are defined in the C++ standard as doing the same thing - dereference the held pointer and return a reference to the object being pointed at.

However, from a debugging standpoint, there *may* be a subtle difference, depending on implementation.  `get()` is defined as returning the held pointer as-is, whether it is `nullptr` or not.  The smart pointer has no concept of what the caller will do with that pointer afterwards.  However, dereferencing a `nullptr` is *undefined behavior*, and knowing that, it is *possible* that a smart pointer implementation *MAY* decide to have its `operator*` throw a runtime error if the held pointer cannot be dereferenced, to aid with debugging efforts.

This is mentioned on cppreference, at least for [`std::unique_ptr::operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*):

> **may throw**, e.g. if `pointer` defines a throwing `operator*`

Comment: Note that `get()` doesn't return `T*`, but `pointer`, which may be some custom type specified in the `Deleter` type of the `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>`. What that note in cppreference is saying is that `*uptr` can throw because `*get()` can throw because `p` can be of a custom type `pointer` rather than `T*`. In other words, there is no difference, not even a subtle difference, not depending on the implementation.

Comment: @Justin what you say is true about `get()` returning `pointer`. But if `pointer` is just a raw `T*` then `*get()` can't validate the pointer at runtime, but `smart_ptr::operator*` may still be able to, depending on whether the *implementation* decides to use such logic when `pointer` is a raw `T*` and ignore such logic when `pointer` is another type with its own `operator*`. So, I stick by my answer.

Comment: I see your point. `*NULL` is undefined behavior, so the library could add a null-check for debugging purposes. Interesting. I suspect none will throw an exception because `-fno-exceptions`, but they could have an `assert(...)` or something similar

Comment: @Justin for instance, Microsoft is known to add debugging asserts and exceptions to the debug version of its libraries, even if the standards don't say that is needed.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference.  The standard in [[unique.ptr.single.observers]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/unique.ptr.single.observers) and [[util.smartptr.shared.obs]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/util.smartptr.shared.obs) both define `operator*` as being `*get()`.

---

`get` should be used when you need a raw pointer to the managed object for passing to something that only excepts a raw pointer.  Otherwise, `*` and `->` are overloaded for the smart pointers to apply those operations to the managed pointer.

---

You could be tempeted to use `&*smart_ptr` to get a raw pointer to the managed object, but `&` is an operator that can be overloaded and could give you the wrong result.  the proper way to get the address (a pointer) would be `std::addressof(*smart_ptr)`, but using `smart_ptr.get()` is shorter.